# java String.format: numbers with localization

Tags: java, localization, numbers, string-formatting

Is it possible to localize numbers in `String.format` call the same way as `NumberFormat.format` does?

I've expected it simply to use

```
String.format(locale, "%d", number)
```

but this doesn't return the same result as `NumberFormat`. For example:

```
String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%d", 1234567890)
```

gives: "1234567890", while

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN).format(1234567890)
```

gives: "1.234.567.890"

If it can't be done, what's recommended way for localizing text including numbers?

Comment: why don't you parse your "String-Number" into a number first and do the formatting with number formatter afterwards?

Comment: My "String-Number" can be a string containing number, so I can't parse it to number.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax), you have to:

- supply a locale (as you are doing in your example)
- include the '`,`' flag to **show locale-specific grouping separators**

So your example would become:

```
String.format(Locale.GERMAN, "%,d", 1234567890)
```

Note the additional '`,`' flag before the 'd'.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `String.format()` is to use MessageFormat:

```
MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("The number is {0, number}", Locale.GERMAN);
String s = format.format(new Object[] {number});
```