# How to validate European Number in Java?

Tags: java

For e.g:
these are valid European numbers (Portuguese numbers)
`1.234,56`
`1 234,56` (Single Space),
`1.234.567,89`,
`1 234 567,89` (Single Space),
`1  234,56` (double space could be replaced by single space...people usually write in double space)

Invalid European numbers (Portuguese numbers)
`1,234.56`,
`1.234 56` (Single space but used as decimal seperator),
`1,234,567.89`,
`1  234.56` (Double space instead of single space).

Can you tell me how to solve this problem? I have been using some pattern matching but it's not effective. And is there any third-party library for this? This is my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ValidateEuropeanNumber {

    /**
     * Checks if the input string represents a valid European number format.
     *
     * Preconditions:
     *  - The input string must not be null.
     *
     * Postconditions:
     *  - Returns true if the input string represents a valid European number format.
     *  - Returns false if the input string does not represent a valid European number format.
     *
     * @param input The string to check for a valid European number format.
     * @return true if the input string represents a valid European number format, false otherwise.
     * @throws NullPointerException if the input string is null.
     */
    public static boolean isValidEuropeanNumber(String input) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(input, "The input string must not be null.");

        // Remove leading and trailing spaces
        input = input.trim();

        // Replace multiple spaces with a single space
        input = input.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");

        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMAN);
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.###", symbols);
        format.setParseBigDecimal(true);

        try {
            BigDecimal number = (BigDecimal) format.parse(input);

            // Check if there are any periods in the input
            if (input.contains(".")) {
                DecimalFormatSymbols periodSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.UK);
                DecimalFormat periodFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.###", periodSymbols);
                periodFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);

                BigDecimal periodNumber = (BigDecimal) periodFormat.parse(input);
            }

            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java String.format: numbers with localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763700/java-string-format-numbers-with-localization)

Comment: @user2342558, the reason this is not good for this problem is that the link is for formatting numbers. What I need is parsing them. Say I pass a string of "1.234,56" and I want this to get converted to English number (i.e 1234.56) for calculation part. But to convert first we need to check whether this is a valid European number or not. After checking we can convert it.

Comment: If you are parsing user input you should be as forgiving as possible with regards to format, being strict only in what is semantically meaningful: the decimal indicator.  Everything else can be ignored.  So just remove spaces, NBSPs and punctuation that is ***not*** the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Java expect Portuguese decimal numbers to use:

- one non-breaking space (NBSP) for each thousands separator
- a comma for the decimal separator.

Note that a non-breaking space is *not* the same as a standard keyboard space. In Windows, I can type a NBSP using `alt+0160` (hold down the `ALT` key and type `0160`).

One approach is to parse each string to a number, and then format the result back to a string:

```java
String langTag = "pt-PT"; // Portuguese-Portugal
NumberFormat nf_ptPT = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag(langTag));

//String input = "1 234,56"; // regular keyboard characters
String input = "1 234,56"; // space is a non-breaking space (alt-0160)

Number number = nf_ptPT.parse(input);
String output = nf_ptPT.format(number);
System.out.println(input + " : " + (output.equals(input) ? "valid" : "invalid")
         + " for locale " + langTag);
```

If the "before" and "after" strings match, you have a valid format for the given locale. (If you get a `ParseException`, then obviously that is also a failure.)

For my version of Java (v 19) the commented out test case fails: `1 234,56` with a regular keyboard space. The other case passes (using a NBSP).

A validation method might look like this:

```java
private boolean isValidLocalNumber(String numberString, NumberFormat nf) {
    if (numberString == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Number number;
    try {
        number = nf.parse(numberString);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        return false;
    }
    return nf.format(number).equals(numberString);
}
```

---

It's not sufficient to *only* parse the string. Trying to parse this:

```
"1.234,56"
```

...using the parser results in a numeric value `1`. Everything from the `.` onwards is discarded. Formatting this `1` back to a string allows us to see that the values are different.

---

If you receive data for Portuguese numbers with those other formats you mentioned in your question, such as:

- two spaces for the thousands separator
- a period (full stop) for the thousands separator
- spaces instead of NBSPs (depending on your Java version)

...then those are invalid Portuguese formats, as far as Java is concerned.

You would have to decide for yourself if you need to handle those as special cases, or require strict correctness, from Java's point of view.

You may need to define some custom formats and try those if the standard locale format fails. I think this could get very messy...

This example is actually for a currency format - not just a decimal number - but it shows what I mean:

```java
Number rawNumber = 120798700;  
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();  
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();  
dfs.setCurrencySymbol("€");  
dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');  
dfs.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator(',');  
((DecimalFormat) nf).setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);  
System.out.println(nf.format(rawNumber.floatValue() / 100))
```

This prints:

```
€1.207.987,00
```

---

In my sample code I have used:

```
String langTag = "pt-PT";
```

This is a BCP 47 language tag, just as a convenient way to set the locale. More information is [here](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/).

It's not the only way to set a locale.

---

**Update**

It's worth adding that trying to use Java to validate decimals-as-strings gets more complicated when you consider that different European (and worldwide) locales have quite a variety of different [CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/) rules.

Looking only at the thousands separator:

- Portuguese (Portugal): non-breaking space (U+00A0)
- English (United Kingdom): comma (U+002C)
- French (France): narrow non-breaking space (U+202F)
- German (Germany): full stop (U+002E)
- French (Switzerland): narrow non-breaking space (U+202F)
- German (Switzerland): right single quotation mark (U+2019)

That last one (Swiss German) looks like this:

```
1’234.56
```